# Sqlite3, Blob type in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, blob

Hi everyone this is sabby. I am getting the data from a webservice and saving that data in sqlit3 database in iphone.I used the data type of video url as blob,but its not saving in database.But if i use the varchar then url is saved in database.
Just help me for this ,as i am new to iphone development.

Thanks everyone

Comment: This sounds like the same question another user, parvind, asked only 15 minutes ago. Strange. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004374/upload-video-in-sqlite-in-iphone/4004394

Comment: Well thanks buddy but i sorted out the problem.I went through your comments which you have written in parvind's profile,yup i also agree that its not good practice to store large video in sqlite using blob type.But what to do when the client really wants that.I had the problem of not saving the blob type video,then i again deleted the files from simulator,again uploaded the database file to my app,now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Dont store BIG blobs in the SQLite. Use a key value pair to match the file to the key. This will be faster.

Comment: Yes I agree, So whats your idea..where would you suggest to save the video...You are answering a question asked 2 years ago...But no problem...That was at my initial phase

Comment: Store the videos on the disk. Use key value to reach the video. For ex: v1 -> /Documents/videos/v1.mpg , v2 -> /Documents/videos/v2.mpg and so on. You can access the videos using the key. This is faster for bigger files, than storing the entire video on the DB.

Comment: That is one of the solution I had ended up...Thanks..though I would be thinking that you would provide some different idea...