# how to store video file in sqlite database in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I want to capture videos in my application and this video should be stored  in sqlite database.
pls tell me the code how can i do this?

thanx.

Comment: You should just save them in the document directory and save the name in the SQLite database.

Comment: is it same as we do for images?

Comment: But you database will gat huge.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004374/upload-video-into-sqlite

Comment: I think @rckoenes is correct. You should save the name of the video in database and the original video file in Documents Directory of the app. This would save you from lot of processing and conversion of videos into NSData and then overhead of inserting it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying save the entire video in database please avoid that approach,its entirely wrong .Save that videos in your document folder with some name and save that name in database. Your approach  take so much memory

Comment: I think you are 14 mins late. Please check this has already been suggested.